# Bounty award UI flow does confirm and time checks in the wrong order

Tags: feature-request, bounty, user-interface

I found a good answer that I thought had gone rather unrewarded, so I added a bounty to the question. I was pretty sure I had to wait a bit before awarding it, but nevertheless, I tried to award it immediately.

I got an alert dialogue asking:

> Are you sure you want to award your bounty to this answer? THIS CANNOT BE UNDONE!

I confirmed that this is what I wanted, and a red hover-over briefly appeared, saying:

> You may award your bounty in 23 hours.

It seems redundant to ask the user if they're sure they want to do something if it cannot be done anyway. Could the time check come first, so that the alert question is not put to the user?

Comment: Is this not similar to the voting buttons in your own posts or in posts where voting is locked, for example?

Comment: @yivi: do you mean the style of notification is similar? For what it is worth, they are not - the "you may award your bounty" floats in free space, next to the post score, and needs to be dismissed manually, whereas the warning about voting on your own posts slides in from the top and auto-dismisses. They're also different colours (red and pink).

Comment: No, similar in the sense that voting buttons could be completely disabled when not really available; but the choice has been made (maybe for performance and/or consistency reasons) not the get that information until the user actually tries to perform the action.

Comment: @yivi: I agree that disabling the award button would solve the problem, but then that might create a fresh problem, which is that the user doesn't understand why the button is disabled. Disabling voting buttons on own posts is a bit better, since it should be obvious why one cannot do that, but perhaps it is better to have explicit error messages for truly lost people?

Comment: I'm not saying disabling UI elements is better (or worse, for that matter.). I'm just saying that this seems to be the same kind of design choice. Until the status is actually needed (the user really trying to award the bounty), it's not retrieved.